# delete plugin for vlc doesnt work anymore

Tags: windows, lua, vlc, delete-file

i updated vlc 2 days ago from 3.0.12 to 3.0.18 and all of a sudden the script wasnt working anymore. it deletes it from the playlist but not from the drive. i then came across the updated version, but i still have the same problem and i dont know why.

someone an idea what i did wrong (aside from updating xD )? i didnt change anything else in that timeframe from it working to not working.

another lesson learned in regards of never change a running system.
(the plugin in question is from here: [VLC Media Player LUA Extension fails detecting whether the media file actually exists or not in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73116210/vlc-media-player-lua-extension-fails-detecting-whether-the-media-file-actually-e/76078880#76078880)
i asked my question there as well, cause i thought it was related to that, but instead got downvoted and deleted, sry if i broke a rule xD)

i didnt triy much tbh, cause i cant identify the problem realy.

searched for the script itself, maybe there is a new version, but there wasnt.
stumbled across another version cause there seem to be lua-related issues, but that version (from the linked post) doesnt work either and i think version 3.0.12 should already be affected ?)

noticed that i cant create a file in the lua folder and thought that it maybe cant executed/used properly, but it was working 2 days ago before i updated vlc, so im out of ideas.

Comment: i found another script
https://gist.github.com/crmaxx/45fc0b22318e4593fb34ed921449d5ba
but that is also not working. i have no clue why.
does those work for others then ? if so, what version of vlc do you use?